# Camelot fail to detect table from PDF document

Tags: python, python-camelot

I am trying to extract table from the pdf document . Installed camelot-py==0.10.1 and 64bit GostScripts on my windows server 2019 (All environment variable are set).Rebooted the machine. On reading the PDF no table is returned. The same package is installed on another windows server 2019 machine and it's working fine. Camelot read_pdf is able to detect the tables. Appreciate if I can get some pointer to help resolve this problem

```py
import camelot
tables=camelot.read_pdf(r"e-tax-guide-2.pdf")
print(tables)
```

Output:

```
<TableList n=0>
```

Comment: Please remember that if not specified Camelot only analyzes the first page. Are your tables in the first page?

Comment: PDF have multiple pages and multiple tables. I have tried with specific page no and , with all pages. Still TableList returned is 0.Installed and Uninstalled camelot versions 0.10.1 few times with reboot and surprisingly it start to work. Not sure how.

Comment: Give pages="all"; `tables=camelot.read_pdf(r"e-tax-guide-2.pdf", pages='all')`